# word-wrap:break-word in 100% table-cell

Tags: html, css

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nw4dF/** 
So, why in my table-cell #c, the css rule `word-wrap:break-word` is ignored and cause the elongation of the table in case of overflow? I don't want use `word-break: break-all;`, how to solve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Break long word in table cell with percentage widths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314238/break-long-word-in-table-cell-with-percentage-widths)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `word-break` instead of `word-wrap` for webkit + opera and `hypehns` for moz and IE10+ (you need a `lang` attribute declared).
For earlier versions of IE you'll just have to use `word-break: break-all`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nw4dF/10/)

#### HTML

```
<div id="a" lang="en">
    ...
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#c {
    *word-break: break-all;
     word-break: break-word;

    -moz-hyphens: auto;
     -ms-hyphens: auto;
         hyphens: auto;
}
```

Comment: ...and for IE,Firefox,Opera?

Answer (score 0):

try this   -  jsfiddle.net/nw4dF/1/

or you could change table syntax on div or something more flexible

Comment: Are u kidding? How can it work? The 80% of the page minus the image are always 400px? xD

Comment: dude i dont know about ur site logic format pages, just try to manipulate with width, this only way to make word-wrap works

Comment: Ok, but you just have to see that does not work simply by doing a little 'zoom out ...