# table - td width in percentage with overflow not working

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to build a table that contains a `td` which has a `width` set in percentage and when overflown a horizontal scrollbar.

Unfortunately I don't manage to make this happen.

http://jsfiddle.net/ne45s2wf/1/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>cell 1
                </td>
                <td>cell 2
                </td>
                <td class="too-long">cell 3 loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 500px;
    background-color: red;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
}

td.too-long {
    background-color: darkgreen;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

1. First thing I wonder is what is the `td`-width in percentage relative to? And is it possible to set it to be relative to the `table`?
2. I would set a maximum width in percentage for the `td` with `overflow hidden`. While this works for the `td`, the parent containers do not align their width to the `td` child when its width is set with percentage. The parents width is as if the child did not have any width set. Furthermore the table now is not "responsive" any more.

Comment: Tabular widths are complicated. See spec for [auto tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#auto-table-layout) and [fixed ones](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#fixed-table-layout)

Comment: You need to be more clear. We can't even know what you want

Comment: Perhaps this is the same issue you have? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314238/break-long-word-in-table-cell-with-percentage-widths

Answer (score -1):

I would take a look at bootstrap. I am not sure exactly what you mean but it seems like you are having trouble with your tables overflowing. Bootstrap has responsive tables which will scroll in the way you specify at small sizes. Take a look at this:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive